# PHP/MYSQL: Unsure why variable does not contain a value

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone please explain why this code is not outputting a value for `$consultant`
When the data base is as follows:

[image]

And below is the code...

```
<?php include ("include/config.php");


$SUC = mysql_query("

    SELECT `decisionValue` FROM `teamdecision` WHERE `decisionType` = 'SUconsultant'

")or die($SUC."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

$SUNumR  = mysql_num_rows($SUC);
$consultant = array();

$i="0";

while ($i<$SUNumR && $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($SUC))
{

    $consultant[$i] = $row['SUconsultant'];
    echo $consultant[$i];
    $i++;

}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: uuummm because your only selecting `decisionValue` from the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `$consultant[$i] = $row['decisionValue'];`?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to other answers, The `$i` counter in your script is completely unnecessary. Here's a much simpler approach:

```
<?php 
include('include/config.php');

$SUC = mysql_query("SELECT decisionValue FROM teamdecision WHERE decisionType = 'SUconsultant'") or die(mysql_error());

$consultant = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($SUC))
{
    echo $consultant[] = $row['decisionValue'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not selecting `SUconsultant` as one of your columns, so why are you expecting it to be in the result row?

```
SELECT `decisionValue` FROM `teamdecision`
```

Whatever key you're referencing in your result set, you should select it as well.

Comment: SUconsultant is a value, not a column -- though you're still right about the general reason.

Comment: SUconsultant is a value, not a field. Look at the screenshot. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are only selecting `decisionValue` in your SQL query, change it to:

```
SELECT `decisionValue`, `SUconsultant` FROM `teamdecision` WHERE `decisionType` = 'SUconsultant'
```